# Set Comment.created_by to another user via Active Collab API

Tags: api, activecollab

Using the Active Collab API, can a comment be created on behalf of another user? Like it's possible with everything else by setting `created_by_id`.

Using:

```
POST http://AC-SERVER/api/v1/comments/discussion/30 HTTP/1.1
{"body":"TEST","created_by_id":5,"updated_by_id":5}
```

the creator isn't set correctly (with every other datatype, it works well):

```js
{"single":
  {"id":81,
   "class":"Comment",
   "url_path":"\/comments\/81",
   "attachments":[],
   "is_trashed":false,
   "trashed_on":null,
   "trashed_by_id":0,
   "parent_type":"Discussion",
   "parent_id":30,
   "body":"TEST",
   "body_formatted":"TEST",
   "body_plain_text":"TEST",
   "created_on":1474039019,
   "created_by_id":1,
   "updated_on":1474039019,
   "updated_by_id":5
  }
 }
```

See `"created_by_id":1`.

Comment: API does not allow that for comments. It always posts them as the person who's token was used. Can you please tell me why you need to change the user?

Comment: @Ilija I'd like to import OTRS-Tickets into AC's discussions.
OTRS-Articles should become AC-comments and should keep the creator.

Comment: Thanks, we'll consider option to change author via API in the future.

Comment: Hi Ilija, no other workaround possible? It's important for me to get OTRS-Tickets/Articles into AC, because in OTRS a lot of pre-work is done what cannot be transferred into AC (1st Level Support like you're doing with Groove)

Comment: Not at the moment. System will use the user who makes the request as author of the comment, always.

Comment: @Ilija Maybe we could patch a .php-File on the server until an official API-change might be released? Could you tell me where the created_by_id-value is overwritten?
I know this isn't a nice solution, but we have to get Tickets with multiple OTRS-Articles into AC.

Comment: @Ilija Could you please give me a hint regarding my question? Thanks.